# Highlight Selected Image in Form - with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, image, forms, highlight

I've searched Google for the answer and have found nada so even a link to a page showing how to do the following will be much appreciated.

Basically I have a form with nothing but images

```
<form>
<input type="image" src="image.jpg" value="image_value">
<input type="image" src="image2.jpg" value="image_value2">
</form>
```

I want to be be able to highlight in some way the image the user has selected. Even just an outline around image 1 when the user clicks image 1 would be perfect.

I already am using Jquery on this project so if there is a jquery solution it would be the handiest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An [accessible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility) approach would be to style radio buttons labels to behave like an image select:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="example" id="ex1" value="ex1" checked />
    <label for="ex1" class="label">Example 1</label>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="example" id="ex2" value="ex2" />
    <label for="ex2" class="label">Example 2</label>
</form>
```

And then the CSS. As you can see, the radios themselves are concealed with an opacity of 0:

```
.radio {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.label {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/mW6xr2I.png);
    text-indent: -999em;
    border: 10px solid white;
    width: 126px;
    height: 126px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    border: 10px solid orange;
}
```

Here's an example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/RH98R/

This has the added benefit of not having a dependency on jQuery (or even javascript for that matter)!

Comment: As the person with the currently accepted answer (which I wrote 5 years ago!), I agree this is a much better solution, and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Since I have no control over the acceptedness of my answer, I've updated my answer with a big bold note pointing to yours.

Comment: (I didn't even notice this answer until now)

Comment: I've changed this to the accepted answer! Thanks :)

Comment: For good measure I always add `overflow: hidden;`. Check out the [Image Replacement Museum](https://css-tricks.com/the-image-replacement-museum/) on CSS-Tricks.com 

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE: Please see [bryanbraun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23507576/480943). His is much better.**

---

In HTML, `<input type="image">` is just a submit button with an image as its face. I don't think that's what you want. You probably want a list of actual images, that when clicked, sets a hidden form value according to a "data-value" attribute. So your HTML should look something like this:

```
<form id="select-form">
    <img src="image.jpg" data-value="image_value">
    <img src="image2.jpg" data-value="image_value2">
    <input type="hidden" id="image-value" name="selected_image" value="">
</form>
```

Then in your javascript, you want to both highlight the image and set the hidden value, like this:

```
$('#select-form img').click(function() {
    // Set the form value
    $('#image-value').val($(this).attr('data-value'));

    // Unhighlight all the images
    $('#select-form img').removeClass('highlighted');

    // Highlight the newly selected image
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
});
```

Finally, set some styles for the highlight class in your CSS file:

```
img.highlighted {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I did not know about data-value!

Comment: `data-value` isn't anything in particular, it's just a custom attribute. By convention (in HTML 5), custom attributes start with `data-` but the rest can be anything. I chose `data-value`, but `data-name` or `data-whatever` are also fine. See http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ for more details.

Comment: Obviously missed that addition in HTML 5, thanks for the link! I'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep yet!

Comment: @Sean, how did it not work out? Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to do. You want a form where someone can select from a set of images, right? And it highlights the one they selected. If that's what you want, this code should work.

Comment: No I used your code, it seemed prefect but it did not work.. http://pastebin.com/hpFwAf6P

Comment: @Sean, it doesn't work because there are a number of problems with the way you put the code together: You didn't include jQuery, you didn't put the click handler in a $(document).ready, and you didn't assign a type to the style block. I've correct these things here: http://pastie.org/1297686

Answer (score 0):

The following will give every image input a 1px border and 10px padding when clicked, but ideally you should give them a class to target them with like: `$(".imgs2higlight").bind()`

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input[type='image']").bind('click',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css({padding : '10px', border: "1px solid blue"});
            })
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work, you could make the styles CSS classes and change the style more easily though.

```
$("input[type='image']")
    .focus(function() { $(this).css("border","solid 1px #f00"); })
    .blur(function() { $(this).css("border","0"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

CSS:

```
.selected { border: 1px solid black; }
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
     $("input[type=image]").click(function(){ $(this).addClass('selected'); });
});
```