# Making "image select" accessible

Tags: html, accessibility

I want to build an "image select" feature into my form, like this:

[image: Add a Landing Page]

There are some good suggestions on how to do this (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178575/1154642), but they typically involve fake form elements made from img or div tags. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="form-behavior.js"></script>
<form id="select-form">
    <img src="image.jpg" data-value="image_value">
    <img src="image2.jpg" data-value="image_value2">
    <input type="hidden" id="image-value" name="selected_image" value="">
</form>
```

This can't be accessible. How can I keep the integrity of the design, and build it in an accessible way?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj8Eg/) ?

Comment: That looks good! I thought the display:none might prevent the radios from being clicked, so I did some research. Apparently, you can set opacity to 0, like shown here: http://www.wufoo.com/guides/custom-radio-buttons-and-checkboxes/. If you update the fiddle and submit it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: FYI, I took what I learned from this question and proposed a better answer to the original question I referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23507576/1154642

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```js
(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on('click', '.image-input-group .image-radio a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var $parent = $this.parent();
  $parent.parent().find('.image-radio').removeClass('active');
  $parent.find('input').click();
  $parent.addClass('active');
 }).on('click', '.image-input-group .image-checkbox a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var $parent = $this.parent();
  //$parent.parent().find('.image-radio').removeClass('active');
  $parent.find('input').click();
  $parent.toggleClass('active');
 });
});
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.image-input-group {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 margin: 0 -15px;
}
.image-input-group .image-input {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}
.image-input-group input {
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.image-input-group .image-input a {
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #ccc;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 50px;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #666;
 line-height: 70px;
 position: relative;
 transition: all 0s;
 color: #eee;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background: #aaa; /* Old browsers */
}
.image-input-group .image-input .hidden-check {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 right: 22px;
 top: 22px;
 color: #eee;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #666;
}
.image-input-group .image-input.active a {
 background: #74BD64; 
 /*
 background: #dfa0ff; 
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dfa0ff 0%, #14d7ff 100%); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dfa0ff 0%,#14d7ff 100%); 
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dfa0ff 0%,#14d7ff 100%); 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dfa0ff', endColorstr='#14d7ff',GradientType=0 ); 
 */
 top: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 0px 5px #ccc;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.image-input-group .image-input.active .hidden-check {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <form class="ajaxform col-xs-12" method="post" action="#">



   <div class="image-input-group">
    <div class="image-radio image-input active">
     <input type="radio" checked name="vehicle" value="home" />
     <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
     <div class="hidden-check"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-radio image-input">
     <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="motorcycle" />
     <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-motorcycle"></i></a>
     <div class="hidden-check"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-radio image-input">
     <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="car" />
     <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-car"></i></a>
     <div class="hidden-check"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-radio image-input">
     <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="plane" />
     <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>
     <div class="hidden-check"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-radio image-input">
     <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="rocket" />
     <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></a>
     <div class="hidden-check"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   
   
   <div class="image-input-group">
    <div class="image-checkbox image-input">
     <input type="checkbox" name="travel[]" value="home" />
     <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
     <div class="hidden-check"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-checkbox image-input">
     <input type="checkbox" name="travel[]" value="motorcycle" />
     <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-motorcycle"></i></a>
     <div class="hidden-check"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-checkbox image-input">
     <input type="checkbox" name="travel[]" value="car" />
     <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-car"></i></a>
     <div class="hidden-check"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-checkbox image-input">
     <input type="checkbox" name="travel[]" value="plane" />
     <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>
     <div class="hidden-check"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-checkbox image-input">
     <input type="checkbox" name="travel[]" value="rocket" />
     <a href="#" class=""><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></a>
     <div class="hidden-check"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   
  
  
  
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```